# Trying to Search for partial matching attributes

Tags: java, sql, h2

So I am trying to Query(Java) a Database(h2) for a search function. To search the Query should find entrys where the attributes match partially.

The search can be for every combination of the attributes, therefore the check if they are valid.

- getName() returns an String
- getDescription() returns an String
- getBreed() returns an String
- getRanking() returns an integer
- getBirthdate() returns a LocalDateTime object in the Database it is a Date
  the others are the same datatype in the Database.

  ```
  @Override
  ```

> ```
> public List<Horse> search(Horse mockHorse) {
>     LOGGER.trace("Search horses which match{}", mockHorse);
>     String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE" +
>         "(UPPER(name) LIKE UPPER(%?%)) AND "+
>         "UPPER(description) LIKE UPPER(%?%)"+
>         " AND breed LIKE ? AND ranking=?";
>     // set value to wildcard to match every value
>     if (!mockHorse.getBreed().equals("")) {
>         mockHorse.setBreed("%");
>     }
> ```
>
> (sorry for that format it didnt take it otherwise)

```
    Object[] obj = new Object[]{
        mockHorse.getName(),
        mockHorse.getDescription(),
        mockHorse.getBreed(),
        mockHorse.getRanking()
    };

    if (!(mockHorse.getBirthdate()==null)){
        query+= " AND birthdate <=?";
        obj = new Object[] {
            mockHorse.getName(),
            mockHorse.getDescription(),
            mockHorse.getBreed(),
            mockHorse.getRanking(),
            mockHorse.getBirthdate().toString()
        };
    }

    final String sql = query +';';
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql,obj, this::mapRow);
}
```

However whatever I try to fix it i only get new Errors, currently I am stuck with

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT * FROM HORSE WHERE(UPPER(NAME) LIKE UPPER(%[*]?%)) AND UPPER(DESCRIPTION) LIKE UPPER(%?%) AND BREED LIKE ? AND RANKING=? AND BIRTHDATE <=?;"; expected "), NOT, EXISTS, INTERSECTS, UNIQUE"; SQL
statement:
SELECT * FROM Horse WHERE(UPPER(name) LIKE UPPER(%?%)) AND UPPER(description) LIKE UPPER(%?%) AND breed LIKE ? AND ranking=? AND birthdate <=?; [42001-200]
```

Could you please give me a hint about what I am doing wrong. (I tried removing the ' from the UPPER as well as moving them ouside of the UPPER ('UPPER') and wrapping it arround the % (UPPER('%?%')).

Comment: thanks to both of you i combined it to use || for concatenating now it works perfekt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to use `'%' || ? || '%'` instead of `%?%`.
2. `UPPER` function can be used to emulate case-insensitive `LIKE`, but such emulation can't process some national letters correctly, not every letter has 1:1 mapping between lower case and upper case variants. It's better and simpler to use `ILIKE` instead:

```sql
name ILIKE '%' || ? || '%'
```

3. If your parameter can contain `_` or `%`, you need to escape them with some character and add `ESCAPE` clause to `LIKE` / `ILIKE`:

```sql
name ILIKE '%' || REGEXP_REPLACE(?, '([_%\\])', '\\$1') || '%' ESCAPE '\'
```

In the Java code you need to type `\\` to get `\` in the string (`\\\\` for `\\`). If `_` and `%` aren't used in your parameters, you don't need this additional transformation.

You have two places where your SQL needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `where` conditions.

```
WHERE
    (UPPER(NAME) LIKE UPPER(%[*]?%)) 
    AND UPPER(DESCRIPTION) LIKE UPPER(%?%) 
    AND BREED LIKE ? 
    AND RANKING = ? 
    AND BIRTHDATE <=?
```

The first two conditions are not valid SQL. If you want to do the concatenation of the parameters as search strings in the query, you should have:

```
WHERE
    UPPER(NAME) LIKE CONCAT('%[*]', UPPER(?), '%') 
    AND UPPER(DESCRIPTION) LIKE CONCAT('%', UPPER(?), '%') 
    AND BREED LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
    AND RANKING = ? 
    AND BIRTHDATE <=?
```

Note: since the filter on `BREED` uses `LIKE`, I assumed you wanted wildcards here too.

An alternative would be to generate the concatenated strings within your application. This should be little effort on application side, and sets for cleaner SQL code:

```
WHERE
    UPPER(NAME) LIKE ?
    AND UPPER(DESCRIPTION) LIKE ?
    AND BREED LIKE ?
    AND RANKING = ? 
    AND BIRTHDATE <=?
```